# Is it possible to limit the number of inodes for a user?

Tags: linux, inode, quota

I want to limit the resources available to user by setting a limit on the number of inodes they can create. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure can. Just use setup your system to use quotas like this as [explained here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/); note the `usrquota` and `grpquota` in the `fstab` entry:

> First, you should specify which filesystem are allowed for quota
>   check.
>
> Modify the `/etc/fstab`, and add the keyword usrquota and grpquota to
>   the corresponding filesystem that you would like to monitor.
>
> The following example indicates that both user and group quota check
>   is enabled on `/home` filesystem
>
> ```
> # cat /etc/fstab
> LABEL=/home    /home   ext2   defaults,usrquota,grpquota  1 2
> ```

With that set, then use [`edquota`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/edquota) as [explained on that same page as well](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/):

> Use the edquota command as shown below, to edit the quota information
>   for a specific user.
>
> For example, to change the disk quota for user ‘ramesh’, use edquota
>   command, which will open the soft, hard limit values in an editor as
>   shown below.
>
> ```
> # edquota ramesh
>
> Disk quotas for user ramesh (uid 500):
>   Filesystem           blocks       soft       hard     inodes     soft     hard
>   /dev/sda3           1419352          0          0       1686        0        0
> ```
>
> Once the edquota command opens the quota settings for the specific
>   user in a editor, you can set the following limits:
>
> - soft and hard limit for disk quota size for the particular user.
> - soft and hard limit for the total number of inodes that are allowed
>     for the particular user.

And if your system does not have `edquota` installed, you can install it like this. For example, to install it on Ubuntu just run this `apt-get` command:

```
sudo apt-get install quota
```

On CentOS you would need to install it via `yum` like this:

```
sudo yum install quota
```